# compilation error if use --static flag with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

When I try to compile static, I am getting the following error:

```
gcc  defrag.c -o abc.exe --static
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, the same thing compiles fine without static:

```
gcc  defrag.c -o abc.exe
```

Question: Why did the compilation failed when static is specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring becuase "--static" says that all subsequent libraries in your link command *must* be static ... but you only have a *dynamic* libc on your system.

Recommended solution:

gcc defrag.c -o abc -lc --static -lmystaticlib

If you're just trying to create a static exe for the sake of having a static exe - I'd recommend "don't".  Shared libraries are Good.  For many different reasons.

Here's a good link:

- [Linux static linking is dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430400/linux-static-linking-is-dead)

Comment: Thanks paul. I am building for embedded environment. To save myself from the trouble of having to move all the libraries along with the app, I decided to go with static.

Comment: You might wish to compile a static libc.  You might also look at [ELF Stratifier](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/150677)