# Why does sections related to dynamic linking like .got exist in an executable file generated with static linking?

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, elf

I am learning linking, and came across a question.

If I have a source file main.c:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with static linking:

```
gcc -static -o a.out main.c
```

And then I found that sections related to dynamic linking like .got is in the executable file, which has a size greater than 0:

```
readelf -S a.out
```

Output:

```
There are 33 section headers, starting at offset 0xa4e04:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            080480f4 0000f4 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048114 000114 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .rel.plt          REL             08048138 000138 000088 08   A  0   5  4
  [ 4] .init             PROGBITS        080481c0 0001c0 00002e 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 5] .plt              PROGBITS        080481f0 0001f0 000110 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 6] .text             PROGBITS        08048300 000300 07ab7c 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 7] __libc_thread_fre PROGBITS        080c2e80 07ae80 000076 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 8] __libc_freeres_fn PROGBITS        080c2f00 07af00 000b2f 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 9] .fini             PROGBITS        080c3a30 07ba30 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [10] .rodata           PROGBITS        080c3a60 07ba60 019394 00   A  0   0 32
  [11] __libc_thread_sub PROGBITS        080dcdf4 094df4 000004 00   A  0   0  4
  [12] __libc_subfreeres PROGBITS        080dcdf8 094df8 00002c 00   A  0   0  4
  [13] __libc_atexit     PROGBITS        080dce24 094e24 000004 00   A  0   0  4
  [14] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        080dce28 094e28 00e308 00   A  0   0  4
  [15] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        080eb130 0a3130 000179 00   A  0   0  1
  [16] .tdata            PROGBITS        080ecf90 0a3f90 000010 00 WAT  0   0  4
  [17] .tbss             NOBITS          080ecfa0 0a3fa0 000018 00 WAT  0   0  4
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      080ecfa0 0a3fa0 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      080ecfa4 0a3fa4 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .ctors            PROGBITS        080ecfa8 0a3fa8 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .dtors            PROGBITS        080ecfb0 0a3fb0 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [22] .jcr              PROGBITS        080ecfb8 0a3fb8 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        080ecfbc 0a3fbc 000030 00  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .got              PROGBITS        080ecfec 0a3fec 000008 04  WA  0   0  4
  [25] .got.plt          PROGBITS        080ecff4 0a3ff4 000050 04  WA  0   0  4
  [26] .data             PROGBITS        080ed060 0a4060 000c20 00  WA  0   0 32
  [27] .bss              NOBITS          080edc80 0a4c80 0016d4 00  WA  0   0 32
  [28] __libc_freeres_pt NOBITS          080ef354 0a4c80 000018 00  WA  0   0  4
  [29] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0a4c80 00002a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [30] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0a4caa 00015a 00      0   0  1
  [31] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0a532c 0086e0 10     32 957  4
  [32] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0ada0c 007aed 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Linux static linking is dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430400/linux-static-linking-is-dead) and its answers, the `-static` flag doesn't actually create a statically-linked executable because the C library itself uses dynamic linking.  Thus dynamic-linking-related sections are emitted in the executable.