# Glibc - building statically using Qt creator or forcing a program to use correct version

Tags: linux, qt-creator, glibc

I have the following problem:

Using Qt Creator, I have made a Qt application which requires Glibc_2.14 to run. I now need to run this application on a machine which only provides Glibc_2.11.3. I do not have root rights on the machine, so I cannot update the library.

If I try to run the application, I naturally get the following error message: `/lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./obsluha)`

I was thinking of linking the Qt application with Glibc statically, but how do I do this in Qt creator? Note that I only need to link statically with Glibc, and not Qt itself.

Another possible way would be to simply copy my working copy of `libc.so.6` onto the machine and somehow force the application to use that version (I know this is not a very good idea). This copied into my home directory, and my home directory exported into the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of course creates collisions with the other libc version.

Any feedback would be welcome, whether it is a solution of one of the two methods I proposed, or a different method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of linking the Qt application with Glibc statically

Don't do it: contrary to popular belief, fully-static binaries are *less* portable [when using GLIBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430400/linux-static-linking-is-dead), not more. When you link the binary fully-statically, you will likely receive a warning at link time: `warning: Using 'getpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`. It is also exceedingly likely that your binary will crash when you ignore that warning.

> but how do I do this in Qt creator?

Sorry, I don't know the answer to this. But it's moot.

> Note that I only need to link statically with Glibc, and not Qt itself.

It is *impossible* link GLIBC statically, while linking other libraries dynamically. Use of dynamic libraries *implies* that you are using dynamic loader, and that *implies* that you are dynamically linking against GLIBC.

So what can you do? Some of the possible solutions are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617).