# what is static and dynamic linking

Tags: objective-c, static, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)

Hi ,

please become free me in this confusion

1 )  what is the  ***static and dynamic linking ? ***  and ***static and dynamic library ?***

2)  is there any kind of interaction these two things ?

3)  static library linking as static and dynamic library linking dynamically -- Rate ?

it may good the answer  based on Objective-c

Comment: There are LOTS of good answers to this on stack overflow.  Please search for static, dynamic, linking.

Comment: no upvotes, no accepted. cmon dude you've been a member long enought to figure out how to vote....

Comment: I've heard rumors that Objective-C doesn't always play nicely with static linking, given its dynamic nature, but it's not a language I personally use (yet), so I can't actually corroborate that. Regardless, there are probably few relevant differences between Objective-C and the other C-based languages when it comes to static and dynamic linking. If you understand it in C, you'll have a sufficient grasp of the concept in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Static linking adds libraries to your executable at compile time. Dynamic linking adds them at run time. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Types