# How to compile a project including all Qt needed libraries, QtCreator, Linux?

Tags: qt-creator

First, I am sorry about my English. That's not my language.

I am developing an application in QtCreator, Linux. When the IDE asked me about the libraries I would use, I just leave the selected ones (they was not enabled for unchecking). Now, I have to run the compiled file in RedHat 5, but it doesn't run. It tells "Error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: ...". So, how do I fix this problem?

I should not install Qt libraries in RedHat (it's a server). I prefer to compile the Qt project including needed Qt libraries (into self compiled file, or in the same directory).

Please, can you tell me some idea??

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot install qt you have two main alternatives:

1. Deploy the libraries together with your application (how you do this depends on the way you deploy your application. It may suffice to do a manual copy.)
2. Statically link with the qt libraries. They will then be included in your executable (which will be much larger as a result). [Static linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)

Some pros and cons of static vs dynamic linking are discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking).

Comment: Right, that's the idea!! I want to deploy it using a static-linking method. What should I do to make a static-linking deployment?