# Is a statically linked executable faster than a dynamically linked executable?

Tags: performance, dll, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Since the dynamically linked libraries have to be resolved at run-time, are statically linked executables faster than dynamically linked executables?

Comment: Usually when you dynamically link in a library there is some overhead for calls. A call goes through an intermediary table and since the library itself is mapped read-only, all its variables must also reside outside the library. I don't know the details for Windows however. Usually the overhead is negligible and it is far better to choose dynamic linking. For purposes of code reuse and the ability to upgrade a library with a security hole.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static linking vs dynamic linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)

Answer (score 33):

Static linking produces a larger executable file than dynamic linking because it has to compile all of the library code directly into the executable. The benefit is a reduction in overhead from no longer having to call functions from a library, and anywhere from somewhat to noticeably faster load times.

A dynamically linked executable will be smaller because it places calls at runtime to shared code libraries. There are several benefits to this, but the ones important from a speed or optimization perspective are the reduction in the amount of disk space and memory consumed, and improved multitasking because of reduced *total* resource consumption (particularly in Windows).

**So it's a tradeoff:** there are arguments to be made why either one might be marginally faster. It would depend on a lot of different things, such as to what extent speed-critical routines in the program relied on calls to library functions. But the important point to emphasize in the above statement is that it might be *marginally* faster. **The speed difference will be nearly *imperceptible***, and difficult to distinguish even from normal, expected fluctuations.

If you really care, benchmark it and see. But I advise this is a waste of time, and that there are more effective and more important ways to increase your application's speed. You will be much better off in the long run considering factors other than speed when making the "to dynamically link or to statically link" decision. For example, static linking may be worth considering if you need to make your application easier to deploy, particularly to diverse user environments. Or, dynamic linking may be a better option (particularly if those shared libraries are not your own) because your application will automatically reap the benefits of upgrades made to any of the shared libraries that it calls without having to lift a finger.

---

**EDIT:** Microsoft makes the specific recommendation that you [prefer dynamic linking over static linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx):

> It is not recommended to redistribute
>   C/C++ applications that statically
>   link to Visual C++ libraries. It is
>   often mistakenly assumed that by
>   statically linking your program to
>   Visual C++ libraries it is possible to
>   significantly improve the performance
>   of an application. However the impact
>   on performance of dynamically loading
>   Visual C++ libraries is insignificant
>   in almost all cases. Furthermore,
>   static linking does not allow for
>   servicing the application and its
>   dependent libraries by either the
>   application's author or Microsoft. For
>   example, consider an application that
>   is statically linked to a particular
>   library, running on a client computer
>   with a new version of this library.
>   The application still uses code from
>   the previous version of this library,
>   and does not benefit from library
>   improvements, such as security
>   enhancements. Authors of C/C++
>   applications are strongly advised to
>   think through the servicing scenario
>   before deciding to statically link to
>   dependent libraries, and use dynamic
>   linking whenever possible.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the state of your disk and whether or not the DLLs might be used in other processes.  A cold start happens when your program and its DLLs were never loaded before.  An EXE without DLLs has a faster cold start since only one file needs to be found.  You would have to have a badly fragmented disk that's almost full to not have this case.

A DLL can start to pay off when it is already loaded in another process.  Now the code pages of the DLL are simply shared, startup overhead is *very* low and memory usage is efficient.

A somewhat similar case is a warm start, a startup where the DLL is still available in the file system cache from a previous time it was used.  The difference between a cold and a warm start can be quite significant on a sluggish disk.  The one reason that everybody likes a SSD.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so. in most of the cases only a copy of the library in memory per program makes the overall system less memory. suppose you have 100 programs using the libc library statically, and libc is ~2-3MB, so it makes the size of the program increase.
But same in a dynamic we can share stuff, so **fewer bytes in the memory means more bytes in Caches, More bytes in cache means faster.**
Though it has loading overhead, your overall system performance is faster.