# qt shared library including external headers

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I'm trying to separate some of my code and put it in a shared library that I will be able to use from other places. In the documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/sharedlibrary.html

They say that you cannot link to other header files. How would I be able to include shared headers into my shared library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared libraries in the context being discussed in the link you provided are .so (shared object) files (.dll, dynamic link library, on Windows), or static (.lib) libraries.  Qt provides this kind of library; so do many other vendors/projects.  To use them in another application (like yours, for example), you *include* the headers and *link* against the library.

What the article is warning about is `#include`ing header files that a user may not have - i.e. ones that aren't part of your project.  Remember, for someone else to use your new "shared library", they need to include the header file(s) that you provide. If that file includes *other* headers that they don't have, they will get errors.

To avoid this problem, do your `#include`s in your implementation (.cpp) files; that way, they are hidden from future users.  Qt recommends the ["pointer-to-implementation" (pimpl)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom - all the implementation details are hidden from the users of the class, including any and all header files that the implementation depends on.

You can easily do the same thing, even if you don't go all-out with pimpl. The goal is to `#include` in your header only the absolutely required files, hopefully all of which you provide with your library.

Comment: but why hide the files you want to include? woudln't you want the user to be aware of the requirements ? could you give an example of a header that i would want to include that woudln't be absolutely required?

Comment: @chikuba Let's say you have a helper class that never needs to be used directly - it only matters to the guts of the library. Say, a manager class to map pointers to strings as IDs to keep things organized. That's not part of the public interface of your library. If you `#include` that file in the headers of your public interface, all of a sudden *everyone who uses your library* knows about it and needs access to it. In contrast, if you only `#include` it in the implementation files, it becomes part of the .lib file and users don't have to worry about it.

Comment: oh okay. so it gets built into the lib file, even though it's a outside headerfile? I have a few headers to a header-lib which i'm really dependant on

Comment: @chikuba Look into the differences between statically and dynamically linking against the external libraries you're using. If you statically link them into your project, your lib will be stand-alone. If you dynamically link them, users of your library need those files(.so/.dll) also.  Here's a good starting place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking