# .lib messing up Qt compilation

Tags: c++, qt, dll, makefile, static-libraries

the problem is solved, but i'd like to know why there is a problem at all.

In am using Qt Creator and linking an external library. In my .pro when i used

```
LIBS += -LC:/Flicker/empty/ -lLabview_DLL
```

everything went fine and the program worked.

Using

```
LIBS += -LC:/DATA/Vincent/SemiRead/ -lLabview_DLL
```

compiling worked without errors, but in the program a call to one of the librarys functions would result in a crash.

Since the Labview_DLL.dll is the same in both Folders i wondered what might be the problem. I found out that in the last case there was an addidtional .lib file with the same name. After deleting this one everything worked with that folder too.
Is it just a preference for present .lib files? OS is Win7-64

Answer (score 0):

Linking to a dll, is based off of the location of the dll, and isn't necessary at compile time.  The links below may help.

[Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries

Because of this, the "LIBS +=" call tries to do a static link to a library.

Hope that helps.