# Why do we need *.lib files?

Tags: c++, c, header, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I don't seem to understand the need of *.lib files. Let's say I have 3 *.c files:

```
module1.c
module2.c
module3.c
myheaders.c
```

In each .c file we have 2 functions. Now if I call function x in module3.c from module1.c, module1.c knows about function x by looking in myheaders.c.

So if I compile this in VS I get a shiny little portable *.exe with no *.lib file attached, so why and when does one need *.lib files?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)

Comment: "3" ... I don't think it means what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries can be made from groups of related functions that have been tested.  They allow you to reuse code without having to go through the compilation stage each time.

Dynamic or Shared libraries allow you to upgrade parts of your executable without recompiling the executable or altering it.

In larger projects, validation of a program is a large portion of the schedule.  Libraries that have already been tested will shorten the schedule and make everybody happy.

Answer (score 3):

*.lib files are for other programmers who want to use your functions in their own programs.

*.exe files are for end users who just want to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I wrote a compiler. I implement some IO functions (in English - `cout`) to work on windows. If you write code, and want to compile it with my compiler, you don't want to wait on each compilation for my implementation of cout to compile. More than that, you don't care about the HOW, so you don't need the source code (witch will take up some memory). So, instead of recompiling code, you get a *.lib file with the functionality, compiled once by me, no heavy source code to take along.

When you sell someone a program you wrote to use with other programs, you (usually) don't want to give him the source code - just the functionality.

If two languages share the same standard's for functions (or if the linker knows about different standards) I could write some code in one language, compile it to a *.lib, then use it with the different language. That doesn't look useful until you download some third party code written in a language you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

The header files doesn't contain the function, they only contain there prototypes so the compiler know how to call them. In the case of predefined functions, they are precompiler seperatly as .lib file which refers to (library) so to call them you will need that .lib file and the header so the compiler know how to call them. when you compile using VS or any compiler, there is another process called the linking which links these files as a single executble.

Answer (score 0):

Because library can be use in a lot of programs. 
Your header file is necessary only for your prof

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.

*.exe stands for executable. This executable could be used to run the program from End user or developer.

*.lib could be used when someone wants to use functions from your code.

There are two types of linking libraries. Static linking and Dynamic linking. follow this question to understand the difference between both of them.

[Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)