# How c++ linking process works?

Tags: c++, linker, standard-library, std

I have experience in PHP, JS and C#.

I use tutorials from http://learncpp.com to learn C++. But now I have some questions about linking process of C++ Standard Library:

1. I have heared that C++ Standard Library is automatically linked to C++ programs. Is it possible to prevent this? (I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express)
2. Is C++ Standard Library present on major OS(s) such as Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and Unix?
3. If the answer of Question No2 is true, so why some programs redistribute the Microsoft C++ 2010 Redistributables?
4. Where C++ Standard Library is actually located on various Operating Systems?
5. How it's possible to embed Required C++ Standard Library files into the application?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. Maybe. 2 answered by 3. 4. It isn't, it's part of the compiler platform. 5. is unclear.

Comment: @KerrekSB: 4. depends on the implementation and how it's configured.

Comment: Would you please explain it a little simpler for me,i'm a beginner c++ programmer

Comment: BTW: You should really learn modern C++. This tutorial is from 2007, and only has a small appendix starting you on C++11 (C++0x). (C++14 is current).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking Also see LTO, and others. Anyway, you want a tutorial, which is *too broad* by far.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to avoid linking the C++ standard library (most compilers have their own standard C++ library)? Also, read [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker) wikipage, and [Levine's book: *Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Comment: @Deduplicator what resource do your recommend to learn C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have heared that C++ Standard Library is automatically linked to C++ programs. Is it possible to prevent this? (I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express)

Not sure about MSVC++2010, but in GCC you add the `-nostdlib` flag to the linker flags. This isn't really recommended unless you know what you're doing, since among those libraries are the runtime that makes sure things like static constructors and destructors get called, variables are initialized, and free space is cleared, in addition to calling `main`. (One case where it's useful is in embedded systems with no OS.)

> Is C++ Standard Library present on major OS(s) such as Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and Unix?

Yes. It's part of the toolchain.

> why some programs redistribute the Microsoft C++ 2010 Redistributables?

Because Microsoft decided to implement part of the runtime as a shared library (a.k.a. DLL) instead of just statically linking all of it, or making the shared library a standard part of Windows. Also, it may include Windows-specific APIs that Microsoft added which aren't technically part of the C++ standard libraries.

> Where C++ Standard Library is actually located on various Operating Systems?

Buried somewhere in your toolchain. In the case of GCC, you use the `gcc-config -L` command:

```
$ gcc-config -L
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/32
$ ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3
32             hardenednopie.specs     libgomp.la        libstdc++.a
crtbegin.o     hardenednopiessp.specs  libgomp.so        libstdc++.so
crtbeginP.o    hardenednossp.specs     libgomp.so.1      libstdc++.so.6
crtbeginS.o    include                 libgomp.so.1.0.0  libstdc++.so.6.0.17
crtbeginT.o    include-fixed           libgomp.spec      libsupc++.a
crtend.o       libgcc.a                libitm.a          libsupc++.la
crtendS.o      libgcc_eh.a             libitm.la         plugin
crtfastmath.o  libgcc_s.so             libitm.so         vanilla.specs
crtprec32.o    libgcc_s.so.1           libitm.so.1
crtprec64.o    libgcov.a               libitm.so.1.0.0
crtprec80.o    libgomp.a               libitm.spec
```

> How it's possible to embed Required C++ Standard Library files into the application?

They're linked like any other library, so if you want to hard-wire them in, you use the static versions of these libraries. In Unix-type OSes, you just link to the `.a` versions of the libraries instead of the `.so` versions. I'm not sure DLLs *have* static versions, though...

Comment: The default setting is Visual Studio is to link to the DLL version of the standard library, but you can change it to link to the statically linked version. Look under Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library and select **Multi-threaded** instead of **Multi-threaded DLL**.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't decided to link the run-time as a DLL. They have provide the run-time as static library as well. They only have decided to set the default to linking against the DLL. It's up to you to designed if your executable depends on the redistributables or not.