# How statically linked binaries could be smaller than dynamically linked binaries?

Tags: linux, linker, glibc, static-linking, dynamic-linking

If you read the description about [stali](http://sta.li/), it mentions about statically linked binaries size:

> It also targets binary size reduction through the avoidance of glibc
>   and other bloated GNU libraries where possible (early experiments show
>   that statically linked binaries are usually smaller than their
>   dynamically linked glibc counterparts!!!).

I don't understand how including libraries in the binary itself will make the binary smaller than a binary with libraries included(Maybe there's something I'm missing regarding [statically vs dynamically linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993390/774086)).

How's this possible? Does this only happen on some specific situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how including libraries in the binary itself will make the binary smaller than a binary with libraries included

There is certain overhead that is associated with dynamic linking: e.g. you need `.dynsym`, `.dynstr`, `.got` and `.plt` sections in order to import symbols from `libc.so.6`.

However, unless the main executable is linked with `-rdynamic`, the sizes of these "overhead" sections are usually quite small, and so the claim that a fully-static binary is smaller appears quite dubious.

Answer (score 10):

If you use static linking, the linker can throw out symbols that are not used.

For instance, your library has both `foo` and `bar`, but the executable only uses `bar`, then `foo` will not be part of the executable.

In case of dynamic linking that is not possible, because the linker/compiler cannot know what will be used when building the library.

Aside from that, dynamic linking is a lovely source for errors (like segfaulting because the newer library is incompatible) that can be avoided by linking statically.

Further reading: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/dynamic-linking/