# What's the difference between linking directly and linking as a static libarary

Tags: compilation, static-linking

Are there any differences between

```
gcc a.c b.c -o b.out
```

and

```
gcc a.c -o a.o
ar rcs liba.a a.o

gcc b.c -la -o b.out
```

?

In what circumstances shall I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating library (variant 2) is good when you are going to re-use the compiled module more than once, and the projects are really big (it saves a bit of compile time). Otherwise, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting part of [dmckee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993407/3793000):

> - **Dynamic** linking can **reduce total resource consumption** (if more than    one process shares the same library (including the
>     version in "the    same", of course)). I believe this is the argument
>     that drives it its    presence in most environments. Here "resources"
>     includes disk space,    RAM, and cache space. Of course, if your
>     dynamic linker is    insufficiently flexible there is a risk of [DLL
>     hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).
> - **Dynamic** linking means that bug fixes and upgrades to libraries **propagate** to improve *your* product without requiring you to ship anything.
> - **Plugins** always call for **dynamic** linking.
> - **Static** linking, means that you can know the code will run in very **limited environments** (early in the boot process, or in rescue
>     mode).
> - **Static** linking can make binaries **easier to distribute** to diverse user environments (at the cost of sending a large and more
>     resource hungry program).
> - **Static** linking may allow slightly **faster startup** times, but this depends to some degree on both the size *and* complexity of your
>     program and on the details of the OSs loading strategy.

Read the full answer for more specific info.