# How to run a C++ application built in Visual Studio 2015 on another machine

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, executable, opencv3.0

I have been developing some programs in C++ using Open CV on Visual Studio 2015 and am trying to run the executable produced from building Visual Studio on another machine, but on the new machine it informs me that multiple .dll files are missing. Is there such a way to compile it in Visual Studio that it will not require these .dll files, or is there a way to have all of the .dll files on the new machine?

- I am running in x86 Release and have changed the C / C++ code generation to just Multi Threaded.
- The Open CV I have installed is 3.0, does this cause issues with using Visual Studio 2015?

Cheers

Comment: Look into static vs dynamic linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Visual Studio redistributables on the machine where the application is going to run : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Either have your installer install the redist. Ask the user to do it. Or bundle the libraries manually with your executable.

Comment: How do I bundle all of the libraries manually with the executable? I have tried what a lot of various other people have said but all seem to produce errors

Comment: Microsoft provides the documentation you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx