# bind dynamic library when creating .so

Tags: c++, binding, shared-libraries

I would like to create a dynamic library hello.so on linux with some of my own functions. With ldd, it needs some system libraries like libstdc++.so.

I am wondering if I could fix that this hello.so will always bind to the libstdc++.so when creating hello.so in my computer. Thus, I could send hello.so and libstdc++.so to other people.

Regards,
Feng

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: I want to give my libhello.so to other people. I would like that other people can also use it in his computer. With ldd, I find that libhello.so use libstdc++.so in my computer. I want that libhello.so can always bind to libstdc++.so.

Comment: The version of libstdc++.so in different system could be different.

Comment: "The version of libstdc++.so in different system could be different." -- yes, but why is *that* a problem? You are doing a poor job explaining your actual problem, and without that you are not going to get a good answer.

Comment: Ok. We call the libstdc++.so used in computer 1 is libstdc++1.so. In computer 1, libhello.so works well since it binds to libstdc++1.so. In computer 2, normally g++ will bind libhello.so with libstdc++2.so throught LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc. This could have problems. So, I want to give other people both libhello.so and libstdc++1.so and force libhello.so bind with libstdc++1.so no matter what environment used in  computer 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a program or library for distribution that has
dependencies on dynamic libraries (shared libraries, on unix-like OSes;
DLLs on Windows) you accept as a matter of course that its operability on any 
computer is constrained by the availability of identical or compatible versions of those runtime
dependencies, i.e. you can only distribute to an ecosystem of
compatible hosts. That is the basis of the linux, Windows, MacOS,
android, iOS ecosystems, which function well upon it.

Is you want to distribute software that has no dynamic library
dependencies to maximize its compatibility to the utmost (and beyond
what is normally sought) then you must build it
with [static linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993390/1362568), so that the
binary itself contains all of the code that it needs to execute. To do
this successfully you must have have installed on your system static versions of
all the libraries (such as `libstdc++`) with which you would
by default link the dynamic versions provided with your toolchain.

Unless you have some specific fell-founded requirement to deliver a statically
linked product, don't worry about this.