# How upgrade PHP extension (Libsodium)

Tags: php, libsodium

I'm using [Libsodium-PHP](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php/), and I'm seeing that the `ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat::crypto_pwhash` function produces different results (with the same arguments) when called from the command line versus when called from within the app running on PHP-FPM.

[This tutorial](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md) says:

> Just make sure you install your OS's equivalent of the php7.2-sodium
>   package when you're installing PHP, and all these steps should be
>   taken care of for you.

`phpinfo();` shows:

```
sodium support  enabled
sodium compiled version 2.0.12
libsodium headers version   1.0.11
libsodium library version   1.0.11
```

But for CLI, it shows:

```
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
libsodium library version => 1.0.16
```

My assumption is that the differing Libsodium versions could be what is causing the `crypto_pwhash` function to produce different results.

**So how can I upgrade the Libsodium extension from 1.0.11 to 1.0.16?**

P.S. I know that the CLI version of `crypto_pwhash` is producing the output that I want because it matches the output of Libsodium-js ([demo fiddle here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjojko4vj4?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&hidenavigation=1)).

Answer (score 2):

[libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) and [libsodium-php](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) are not the same thing.

in order to upgrade that, you would have to build `libsodium-php` from source

and link it against `libsodium` headers & library at version `1.0.16`.

while the maintainer of `php7.2-sodium` apparently linked it against `1.0.11` -

possibly even `/etc/php.d` and `/etc/php-cli.d` might reference different modules

---

if `libsodium-php` had been installed with with a package manager or pecl;
better first uninstall that - then you could attempt to build `libsodium-php` from source (`yum install php-devel re2c` first):

```
...
cd libsodium-1.0.16
sudo cp ./src/libsodium/.libs/libsodium.so.23 /usr/lib64/libsodium.so.23
sudo cp ./src/libsodium/.libs/libsodium.so.23.1.0 /usr/lib64/libsodium.so.23.1.0

cd ..
git clone https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php.git
cd libsodium-php
phpize
./configure --help
./configure
make
# sudo make install

sudo cp ./modules/sodium.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/sodium.so
# sudo cp ./modules/sodium.so /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/sodium.so

sudo echo "extension=sodium.so" > /etc/php-cli.d/sodium.ini
sudo cp /etc/php-cli.d/sodium.ini /etc/php.d/sodium.ini
# sudo cp /etc/php-cli.d/sodium.ini /etc/php-zts.d/sodium.ini
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

php -r "phpinfo();" | grep sodium
/etc/php-cli.d/sodium.ini,
sodium support => enabled
sodium compiled version => 2.0.12
libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
libsodium library version => 1.0.16
```

after manually installing it for CLI & SAPI ...I've found the docs for [pecl-libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md); which tell the same:

> If you get different numbers, you won't have access to some of the features that should be in libsodium 1.0.14. If you need them, you'll need to go through the ritual of compiling from source instead (shown above).

still could not get it working for `zts` (thread-safe); those paths should be `fpm` (non thread-safe) on your system (and one can link it against the default PHP headers; no patching should be required)... nevertheless, both `php-cli` and `php-fpm` need to be considered, when adding modules and `.ini`.

Comment: one could even workaround with `shell_exec()` running `php` in the CLI, instead of the SAPI.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand a few things. How does my one machine have both 1.0.11 and 1.0.16 (one for FPM and one for CLI)? How did I get 1.0.16 at all, given that I never compiled anything? And what exactly are you saying I should do to upgrade the FPM one?

Comment: @Ryan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking ...might explain the reason; if both are statically linked, this is entirely possible. building from source and linking against the latest headers/library should result in two equal versions. why exactly the CLI and SAPI display different numbers is hard to tell, unless inspecting all php.ini files.

Comment: It seems that regular Libsodium is coded in C rather than PHP, and its latest version is 1.0.16 (https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases). And my CLI somehow uses that, even though I don't understand how PHP and C work together. My PHP-FPM, on the other hand, seems to point to Libsodium-php (and uses the most recent version of it, 2.0.12 https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php/releases) and also seems somehow connect to a stale 1.0.11 version of regular Libsodium. How can I uninstall Libsodium-php from my PHP-FPM & then hook it up to the 1.0.16 version of Libsodium instead of 1.0.11?

Comment: @Ryan these modules are never coded in PHP. while I've added the script to build from source; along with further documentation. to uninstall, this depends how it had been installed. you could just do a `locate sodium.so` and then `rm` ... if not PHP had already been compiled with it; which one can see in `phpinfo()`, under "Configure Command"... `pecl uninstall libsodium && pecl install libsodium` might be yet another approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!