# When the C# JIT Compiler compiles a .dll to machine code mid-execution, how are the memory addresses resolved with respect to the .exe's machine code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, clr, jit

I am trying become better acquainted with the pros and cons of dynamic-link libraries in C#, and how their advantages and disadvantages compare to the advantages and disadvantages of using dynamic-link libraries in C++.

Here is what I am currently puzzling over: when a C# program that has been running for a while goes to load a .dll that contains managed code, and the JIT Compiler compiles the MSIL of the .dll to machine code and places the machine code in RAM, how are the memory addresses of the .dll's newly-compiled machine code linked to the machine code from the original .exe?

1. Absolute addresses - same as if the code from the .exe and .dll had been compiled in a single machine code executable before running?
2. Linked via load-time relocation of the .dll's machine code?
3. The .dll's machine code is compiled to Position Independent Code (PIC)?

So far, I have found these helpful articles about different ways machine code .dll's are loaded:
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/

...and this StackOverflow question about the pros and cons of static and dynamic linking if the .exe and .dll are both machine code:
[Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)

But I have not been able to find helpful information about how these concepts apply in the world of .NET, MSIL, and the JIT Compiler.

Comment: There is no relocation at all, the jitter generates the code on demand and it doesn't move after that.  There is no practical comparison between a C# dll and a C++ dll, it merely acts as a container of data in managed code.

Comment: @HansPassant Just to clarify what you are saying - you mean the spots in the .exe's machine code that call the .dll's machine code are absolute addresses?

Comment: JIT inserts placeholders for nested calls to non-JITted functions. If there are still placeholders for calls to missing machine code then that is fixed up on actual first run of the function, by further JITting nested calls. So none of you options are really correct: absolute addresses are used, except where not available and JIT needs to fix them up. Options 2 and 3 make no sense in the context of a JIT: the code is after all only compiled at runtime. Moving machine code about only makes sense if using Ahead Of Time compilation (similar to C++ which is precompiled into machine code).

Comment: @Charlieface So does the machine code of the compiled .exe methods and machine code of compiled .dll methods live together in some kind of "soup" in RAM, with no distinction as to the source of the IL that the methods were compiled from, or is there some kind of in-RAM division between machine code that came from the .exe and machine code that came from the .dll - such as sticking them in different address spaces or different parts of the address space?

Comment: Yes, "soup" is the correct mental model.

Comment: @HansPassant I often say the correct way to think about it is: in my personal fully conformant CLR implementation, the memory is stored on the Moon, which is made of cheese, the stack is made of pizza boxes with scribbles on the side, the instructions are written in a recipe book. Or in other words: why do you care?

Comment: @Charlieface I did some more reading - and would it be more accurate to say that the machine code for the methods for all assemblies in the same AssemblyLoadContext are mixed together, but you can force the machine code to be kept separate by loading a .dll using a different AssemblyLoadContext?

Comment: Not really, it's just that an `AssemblyLoadContext` can be unloaded. Effectively they've just made the loaded DLL, static data, associated JIT code and other structures so they can be collected by GC. I don't think there is anything special about the way it's JITted or where the code is stored.

Comment: There is no "machine code" in the compiled .exe, at least not for the application. A .Net exe file contains CIL just like a DLL does, the only real difference between a dll and an exe is a stub to start the CLR. (with exception for "self contained" and AOT compiled programs). But why do you care? It is not like you can do much about the internal details of the CLR.

Comment: @JonasH I'm aware there's no machine code in the .exe. The question is about the relationship between the machine code of the .exe and .dll post-JIT. I could change the internal details of the CLR by making all .cs code files in the .dll be added "as link" to the .exe's project file, thus eliminating the .dll. I care because I want to determine whether the concepts of PIC and load-time relocation apply in the world of C#, which I want to know about because I want to be an expert on the topic. I want to be an expert so I can discuss this intelligibly with people with a c++ background.

Comment: In the .Net world you code against the language specification, or possibly against the CIL specification, where the concept of memory addresses for code does not really exist, at least not the same way as C++. So No, the concepts PIC/reloacation does not apply. Except maybe if you want to write your own CLR implementation? but then you can do whatever you want, including using cheese for storage.

Comment: @JonasH Via the law of leaky abstractions https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/ it is unwise for me to just hand wave how the CLR implementation I am using treats JIT'ing a .dll differently from JIT'ing that same code if it was added to the original .exe via putting the .dll's .cs files in the project directly. Since in other languages static and dynamic linking each have certain effects, I need to be certain those effects don't bleed over into C# in ways I don't expect when I choose to use .dll's over putting the code directly in the project.

Comment: But .net is not an abstraction on top of .lib files or dynamically loaded native libraries. Sure, .net uses "dlls", that are "dynamically loaded", that does not mean PIC/relocation concepts applies. You seem to be "fighting against windmills", i.e. concerned by imaginary issues, while seemingly being ignorant of the real issues in .net, like [library versioning](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/06/30/versioning-limitations-in-net/), .net framework dependency and much more.

Comment: @JonasH The abstraction I am referring to is how building to a CIL specification abstracts away what an particular CLR implementation is doing under the hood in RAM to join JIT dll machine code to the original exe machine code. It is important to ask questions about issues that could be imaginary in order to confirm they are imaginary. I am not ignorant of the other issues, but do not ask on Stack Overflow about them because there are other resources to learn about them and I only resort to Stack Overflow when I can't find any other resources to help me learn about something.

Comment: There is no such thing as "join JIT dll machine code to the original exe machine code". The Jitter does not compile whole assemblies. *Methods* are compiled just in time, with stubs for methods not yet compiled, and the jitter doing its thing, fixing addresses etc as it goes. What dll a method originated from is irrelevant, except that the runtime has to go and find the assembly-file the first time a method in it is called.

Comment: All JIT-produced code is intermingled within an AppDomain.  That why you can't unload individual assemblies, only discard the whole AppDomain at once.  The JIT-produced code is separate from native AOT-compiled machine code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fundamentally missunderstanding how the jitter works.

The jitter works on a per-method basis that basically works something like this. The details will be implementation specific, and I'm no expert in code generation, so some details are surely incorrect.

When a "Call" CIL instruction is encountered it is replaced with a call to a "stub" in the jitter. If/when this is called the jitter will do a few things:

1. Is called method already compiled? If so, change the original call to target the compiled method instead and resume execution.
2. Is the assembly for the method loaded? If not, go find the assembly and load it. There are a bunch of rules governing exactly how this is done. Loading just means loading the CIL code to memory, no compilation is involved.
3. Assuming the assembly is loaded, compile the method to machine code, again replacing any "Call"-instruction with a call to stubs, change the caller address to target this newly compiled method instead of the stub, and resume execution.

In the end you will just have a bunch of machine code. At no point will the jitter compile an entire dll, so there is no need to handle call addresses on a per-assembly level.

Of course, you could make a CLR implementation that does something else, like compiling everything at once. But this will be very difficult to do without at least some stubs to the CLR for generating code on demand, since .Net contains generics and reflection that are difficult to implement otherwise.